# Environment variable equivalent for Next.js static HTML exports

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am serving [a static HTML exported next.js app](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export) in a docker image with nginx. However, I need to make some variables configurable after the image is build (I am not saying runtime since there isn't a run actually, nginx is serving staticly built HTML, JS and CSS files). Since the environment variables are processed during the build, changing them is not an option. Is there a way to make some variables configurable for this scenario?

Comment: How did you end up doing this haha?